# Kohana css images are not appearing after moving site to localhost and href links are not working

Tags: php, kohana

I have downloaded a kohana project from a server to a localhost ubuntu system. I have created a folder for it in var/www/testsite/
I have changed the Kohana::init in the boostrap.php as suggested accordingly

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'      => '/testsite/'
    , 'index_file'  => FALSE
    , 'profile'     => ! IN_PRODUCTION
    , 'caching'     => IN_PRODUCTION
));
```

When I run the site localy, localhost/testsite/ I see the website loading but the images that are loaded by css files are not appearing. The path of a sample image is like this url("/assets/images/testsite/default/background_all.jpg")
If i change the url to url("assets/images/testsite/default/background_all.jpg") the image appears properly.

Also when I click on a link I get

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /testsite/contact/info was not found on this
>   server. Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

This is how my .htaccess is constructed,

```
# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/kohana/, use /kohana/
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
RewriteBase /testsite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Why is it working on the server and not on my localhost?
How can I fix this without changing the url path of the css files?

thank you

Comment: What problem to write like this `url("assets/images/testsite/default/background_all.jpg")` ?

Comment: because on the server it works like url("/assets/images/testsite/default/background_all.jpg") and not like url("assets/images/testsite/default/background_all.jpg")

Comment: You can override `url()` function and fix it.

Comment: how can I do this? Why is it working on the server and not on my localhost? what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file add this line at the beginning: `RewriteEngine On`. This way you will turn on URL rewriting.

Regarding images:

You should edit your image paths by removing `'/'`, so you have `"assets/images/testsite/default/background_all.jpg"`. To make this working you should include your `.css` files like this: `URL::site('static/your.css')`. So your folder structure would be like this: Static folder containing `your.css and assets folder.`

Also you should load all your pictures in the app using: `URL::site('static/img/some_picture.png')`

Comment: this solved my problem of links that were not working. But the url() image paths are still not working